# How to test a method parameter type jagged array with XUnit

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, xunit.net

How can I test a method that takes a parameter of type string[][] ? 
I tried using **InlineData** attribute but it only works with string[]

```
[InlineData(new string[]{ "one", "two", "three"})]
```

but not with

```
[InlineData(new string[][] { new string[]{"one"}, new string[] {"two" } })]
```

What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: that's an array not a list

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I know, sorry about the correct words. It works with the test method parameter type List<string>, though I have InlineData with new string[] as attribute to the test method.

Comment: this isn't about words, it's about types... those are arrays not lists...

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I will edit the question.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is that the types must match; that's why it's not working; array[][] is not the same type as list of lists

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I understood. I changed the question accordingly with correct types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153128/discussion-between-the-bearded-llama-and-codeweed).

Answer (score 2):

Jagged Array as Argument only works by using the 'params' keyword. The jagged array must be the last argument of the test method.
See my example:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(2, 3,
    new[] { "val1", "val2", "val3" },
    new[] { "val4", "val5", "val6" }
)]
[InlineData(3, 2,
    new[] { "val1", "val2" },
    new[] { "val3", "val4" },
    new[] { "val4", "val5" }
)]
public void MyTestMethod(int exptectedOuterCount, int expectedInnerCount, params string[][] myArray)
{
    Assert.Equal(exptectedOuterCount, myArray.Length);

    foreach (var innerArray in myArray)
    {
        Assert.Equal(expectedInnerCount, innerArray.Length);
    }
}
```

Without the params-keyword the compiler do not accept the jagged array.

Comment: what if i want to pass 2 Jagged arrays, the expected result array and the actual array ?